# Using TSQLConnection/SQLite on multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I am in the process of testing an app that has been working on Windows 7 & 8 nicely on OSX, using FireMonkey 2 (XE3).

For some reason I am getting crashes with OSX and the debugger isn't really giving much of a clue as to what the problem is.

Until now I have been using a single TSQLConnection and using this throughout my application and in multiple threads. Since the problems on OSX have been happening, I have been looking at maybe the causes being the TSQLConnection, used in multiple threads.

So I am here hoping to find a definitive answer as to how to use TSQLConnection/SQLite on multiple threads, if there is anything I need to do in order to ensure there are no conflicts with threads or do I just use it as is without having to worry about possible conflicts?

Comment: Hello Jason, I have used SQLite in a multithread solutin in Firemonkey. I would like to help if you can post a small code showing the crash point.

Comment: Hi there, Sorry for not getting back to you, the problem that I had seemed to do with not sync'ing UI updates from threads.
But I do see that OSX isn't as fast as Windows with updating the UI, I'm not sure if it's the db or just Firemonkey in general though.